# Task Completion Notification Alert within a template

Tags: php

```
if  ($this->id == NULL AND ($this->status_id == '62' OR $this->status_id = '63'))
    {
        $notify_url = Route::get('applications')->uri(array('controller' => 'calibration', 'action' => 'details', 'id' => $this->id));

        Notify::create(Kohana::$config->load('tip.top'), 'Calibration',
            $this->id.': '.$this->description,

            Route::get('applications')->uri(array('controller' => 'calibration', 'action' => 'details', 'id' => $this->id))

        );
    }
```

Hi,

I have this code which should send me a notification when the the ID of the record is not NULL , the status of the record is not "In Progress" and the status of the record is "Complete", it should only send me a notification then.

It sends me notifications the complete opposite. When I refresh a blank record & when I add a record, when the status is "In Progress" it send notifications

Any help would,d be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the if condition is exactly how you want? Do check the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) for operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are wrong:

*$this->id == NULL* => When IS null and you say "..when the the ID of the record **is not** NULL..."

Due your instructions your conditional will be:

```
if  ($this->id != NULL AND ($this->status_id == '62' OR $this->status_id = '63'))
```

Regards.